# Upload to S3 from HTTPWebResponse.GetResponseStream() in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, httpwebrequest

I am trying to upload from an HTTP stream directly to S3, without storing in memory or as a file first.  I am already doing this with Rackspace Cloud Files as HTTP to HTTP, however the AWS authentication is beyond me so am trying to use the SDK.

The problem is the upload stream is failing with this exception:

`"This stream does not support seek operations."`

I've tried with `PutObject` and `TransferUtility.Upload`, both fail with the same thing.

Is there any way to stream into S3 as the stream comes in, rather than buffering the whole thing to a `MemoryStream` or `FileStream`?

*or* is there any good examples of doing the authentication into S3 request using HTTPWebRequest, so I can duplicate what I do with Cloud Files?

**Edit:** *or* is there a helper function in the AWSSDK for generating the authorization header?

**CODE:**

This is the failing S3 part (both methods included for completeness):

```
string uri = RSConnection.StorageUrl + "/" + container + "/" + file.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", RSConnection.AuthToken);
req.Method = "GET";

using (var resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility trans = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(S3Client);
        trans.Upload(stream, config.Element("root").Element("S3BackupBucket").Value, container + file.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText);

        //Use EITHER the above OR the below

        PutObjectRequest putReq = new PutObjectRequest();
        putReq.WithBucketName(config.Element("root").Element("S3BackupBucket").Value);
        putReq.WithKey(container + file.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText);
        putReq.WithInputStream(Amazon.S3.Util.AmazonS3Util.MakeStreamSeekable(stream));
        putReq.WithMetaData("content-length", file.SelectSingleNode("bytes").InnerText);

        using (S3Response putResp = S3Client.PutObject(putReq))
        {

        }
    }

}
```

And this is how I do it successfully from S3 to Cloud Files:

```
using (GetObjectResponse getResponse = S3Client.GetObject(new GetObjectRequest().WithBucketName(bucket.BucketName).WithKey(file.Key)))
{
    using (Stream s = getResponse.ResponseStream)
    {
        //We can stream right from s3 to CF, no need to store in memory or filesystem.                                            
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", RSConnection.AuthToken);
        req.Method = "PUT";

        req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        if (req.ContentLength == -1L)
            req.SendChunked = true;


        using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[32768];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }
        req.GetResponse().Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As no-one answering seems to have done it, I spent the time working it out based on guidance from Steve's answer:

In answer to this question "is there any good examples of doing the authentication into S3 request using HTTPWebRequest, so I can duplicate what I do with Cloud Files?", here is how to generate the auth header manually:

```
string today = String.Format("{0:ddd,' 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'zz00}", DateTime.Now);

string stringToSign = "PUT\n" +
    "\n" +
    file.SelectSingleNode("content_type").InnerText + "\n" +
    "\n" +
    "x-amz-date:" + today + "\n" +
    "/" + strBucketName + "/" + strKey;

Encoding ae = new UTF8Encoding();
HMACSHA1 signature = new HMACSHA1(ae.GetBytes(AWSSecret));
string encodedCanonical = Convert.ToBase64String(signature.ComputeHash(ae.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

string authHeader = "AWS " + AWSKey + ":" + encodedCanonical;

string uriS3 = "https://" + strBucketName + ".s3.amazonaws.com/" + strKey;
var reqS3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriS3);
reqS3.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
reqS3.Headers.Add("x-amz-date", today);
reqS3.ContentType = file.SelectSingleNode("content_type").InnerText;
reqS3.ContentLength = Convert.ToInt32(file.SelectSingleNode("bytes").InnerText);
reqS3.Method = "PUT";
```

Note the added `x-amz-date` header as HTTPWebRequest sends the date in a different format to what AWS is expecting.

From there it was just a case of repeating what I was already doing.

Comment: Hi. I want to use this method but the line with file.SelectSingleNode("content_type") does not compile since the "file" is not declared. It also does not appear in your original code. Is it possible that you provide a complete example?

Comment: @SerhatÖzgel `file` is an `XmlNode` filled from a list of files on Rackspace Cloud Files.  Just substitute for the `content type` of whatever file you are trying to upload.  Think of them as just some strings you need to replace for your specific use case.

Comment: @RichardBenson -- I want to hug you - thank's for posting an actual full sample source for this - Amazon could learn a thing or two.

Comment: I was running around trying to figure out why I couldn't get this to work and I realized that this answer is outdated (2013)

AWS has updated to "signature version 4". The method is similar but has more information and steps. A zip with code shows how to do it like the answer here, only more up to date: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Amazon S3 Authentication Tool for Curl](http://aws.amazon.com/code/128). From that web page:

> Curl is a popular command-line tool for interacting with HTTP
>   services. This Perl script calculates the proper signature, then calls
>   Curl with the appropriate arguments.

You could probably adapt it or its output for your use.

Comment: Looks interesting, my Perl knowledge is non-existent, but it looks like lines 232-244 are where the magic happens. This could be a good start, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that according to the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonRequestHeaders.html) Content-Length is **required** and you don't know what the length is until the stream has finished.

(I would guess the Amazon.S3.Util.AmazonS3Util.MakeStreamSeekable routine is reading the whole stream into memory to get around this problem which makes it unsuitable for your scenario.)

What you can do is read the file in chunks and upload them using [MultiPart upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMPDotNetAPI.html).

PS, I assume you know the C# source for the AWSSDK for dotnet is on [Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net).

Comment: I do know my content length because its included in the Rackspace XML response and I am adding it as meta data in the second was option. Makeseekable does just turn it into a memory stream and is the current hacky way of doing it. Multipart upload has to use local files, I tried that too :(

Comment: According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuDotNet.html Multipart upload works with streams.

Answer (score 1):

This is a true hack (which would probably break with a new implementation of the AWSSDK), and it requires knowledge of the length of the file being requested, but if you wrap the response stream as shown with [this class (a gist)](https://gist.github.com/joeenzminger/7460006) as shown below:

```
long length = fileLength;
```

you can get file length in several ways.  I am uploading from a dropbox link, so they give me the 
length along with the url.  Alternatively, you can perform a HEAD request and get the Content-Length.

```
string uri = RSConnection.StorageUrl + "/" + container + "/" + file.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", RSConnection.AuthToken);
req.Method = "GET";

using (var resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        //I haven't tested this path
        Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility trans = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(S3Client);
        trans.Upload(new HttpResponseStream(stream, length), config.Element("root").Element("S3BackupBucket").Value, container + file.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText);

        //Use EITHER the above OR the below
        //I have tested this with dropbox data
        PutObjectRequest putReq = new PutObjectRequest();
        putReq.WithBucketName(config.Element("root").Element("S3BackupBucket").Value);
        putReq.WithKey(container + file.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText);
        putReq.WithInputStream(new HttpResponseStream(stream, length)));
        //These are necessary for really large files to work
        putReq.WithTimeout(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        putReq.WithReadWriteTimeout(System.Thread.Timeout.Infinite);


        using (S3Response putResp = S3Client.PutObject(putReq))
        {

        }
    }

}
```

The hack is overriding the Position and Length properties, and returning 0 for Position{get}, noop'ing Position{set}, and returning the known length for Length.

I recognize that this might not work if you don't have the length or if the server providing the source does not support HEAD requests and Content-Length headers.  I also realize it might not work if the reported Content-Length or the supplied length doesn't match the actual length of the file.

In my test, I also supply the Content-Type to the PutObjectRequest, but I don't that that is necessary.

Comment: This works for me with my existing PutObjectRequest, but AWS does not like having the wrong number of bytes.  I don't think Content-Length can be trusted enough unless you control the server that all the files are being served from.

Answer (score 0):

As sgmoore said, the problem is that your content length is not seekable from the HTTP response. However HttpWebResponse does have a content length property available. So you can actually form your Http post request to S3 yourself instead of using the Amazon library.

[Here's another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030371/http-post-with-httpwebrequest) that managed to do that with what looks like full code to me.

Comment: See my other comment about content length. That question misses out the signature generation functions which is the bit I am struggling with. otherwise I'd do it manually like I have when streaming to Rackspace.