# copy file to S3/https using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy on-premises file to S3 folder location using ssis script task. Can anybody suggest with this approach?

```
string url = Dts.Variables["User::s3filepath"].Value.ToString();
string dest = Dts.Variables["User::source"].Value.ToString();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";

FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
fileStream.CopyTo(dest);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have to provide authentication of some kind...

Comment: You need to use AWS SDK to interact with AWS. You just need to create objects of some classes and call methods on it. https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya restriction to use nuget here

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev using httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? Is there an error message you're getting?

Comment: err at  fileStream.CopyTo(dest) - cannot convert from string to System.IO.Stream

Comment: Check the answer of this question for upload file to s3 via HttpRequest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917768/upload-to-s3-from-httpwebresponse-getresponsestream-in-c-sharp

Comment: Trying with - SSIS script task using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html but getting error for private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;  build succeeded but when executed getting error as "Cannot load script for execution"